# IDX10634: Unable to create the SignatureProvider

Tags: vb.net, cryptography, jwt, rsa

I'm at a loss as to what is wrong here. I'm trying to create a JWT with RS SHA256. At handler.WriteToken I get this error:

IDX10634: Unable to create the SignatureProvider.
Algorithm: 'System.String', SecurityKey: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey'
is not supported. The list of supported algorithms is available here: https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/supported-algorithms

The way I interpret it, it is telling me that I am specifying an unsupported algorithm, yet SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256 resolves to "RS256".

Any guidance would be appreciated. Below is my code.

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
Imports System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt


Public Function GetJWT()
    Dim rsaPrivateKey As String = "MIIEvQI...small piece of key included here...J83wMcqFO4WXjrMXU="
    Dim rsaPrivateKeyBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Base64UrlEncode(rsaPrivateKey))
    Dim securityKey As Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey = New Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(rsaPrivateKeyBytes)
    Dim credentials As SigningCredentials = New Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256)
    Dim header As JwtHeader = New JwtHeader(credentials)
    Dim payload As JwtPayload = New JwtPayload()
    payload.Item("test") = "this is a test"
    Dim secToken As JwtSecurityToken = New JwtSecurityToken(header, payload)
    Dim handler As JwtSecurityTokenHandler = New JwtSecurityTokenHandler()
    Dim tokenString As String = handler.WriteToken(secToken)
    Return tokenString

End Function
Public Function Base64UrlEncode(input As String) As String
    Dim inputBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes).Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_").Replace("=", "")
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link you posted, `RsaSha256` is not a supported *symmetric* algorithm. You need to try a symmetric algorithm, like `SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256`.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're saying -- switching to a symmetric algorithm should make my code work. So technically your answer is correct in that it should fix the error. I must use RSA however (I'm trying to use a service account with google cloud services) so it looks like my real problem is one of how to use RSA. Thank you for getting me headed in the right direction.